# How to bind `$jwt.sub` on Create to property using Neo4j and GraphQL?

Tags: neo4j, graphql, neo4j-graphql-js

I'm currently using neo4j and graphql with an Apollo server.

I have the following type:

```
  type Person {
    id: ID! @id
    externalId: ID
    name: String!
  }

  extend type Person
    @auth(
      rules: [
        { operations: [CREATE, UPDATE], bind: { externalId: "$jwt.sub" } }
      ]
    )
```

And when I try to do the following mutation:

```
mutation Mutation($input: [PersonCreateInput!]!) {
  createPeople(input: [
    {
      "name": "abc"
    }
  ]) {
    people {
      name
    }
  }
}
```

I get a FORBIDDEN error from Neo4j.

I debugged a bit the code, and it looks like this is what's being transformed to:

```
CALL {\n' +
      'CREATE (this0:Person)\n' +
      'SET this0.id = randomUUID()\n' +
      'SET this0.name = $this0_name\n' +
      'WITH this0\n' +
      'CALL apoc.util.validate(NOT(this0.externalId IS NOT NULL AND this0.externalId = $this0_auth_bind0_externalId), "@neo4j/graphql/FORBIDDEN", [0])\n' +
      'RETURN this0\n' +
      '}\n' +
      'RETURN \n' +
      'this0 { .name } AS this0',
```

so if I understand this correctly, if externalID is NULL AND externalID is different from my jwt sub value, then it will throw the exception.

And basically what I'm trying to achieve is:

When creating a person node, assign the externalID value to the value of the `sub` property of my JWT.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the double negative is causing some confusion with the predicate. The exception will be thrown if `this0.externalId` is null OR if  `this0.externalId` does not equal `$this0_auth_bind0_externalId` due to the AND statement and surrounding NOT.

Since you're creating this `this0` above it will never have `this0.externalId`, so this predicate will always be true and the exception will always be thrown.

I'm not strong in GraphQL, but I would think your mutation needs to set the `externalId`.

Comment: I work on this lib and this is the correct answer. To this point, you should make `externalId` required using `!`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, yes the double negative was definitely throwing me off there, and yes, I needed to set the `externalId` as well!